# Sharepoint 2013 edited page stuck at saving

Tags: save

I edited one of my site's pages - added an embedded code which prints a div with a pdf object inside.

**After I click save, it keeps on showing "saving".**

How can I save the changes?

Many thanks

**LATER EDIT**
Finally made it work! Just restored a previous version, made the changes, and it saved itself! Yey!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deleting browser temporary files and cookies? 
Also check out saving in another browser.

Comment: I tried both deleting the history in Mozilla and saving in Chrome, it doesn't work

Comment: Could you please pass in here code , you have writtnen?

Comment: <div style="z-index:3;margin:0 auto;width:845px"><object width="845" height="997" id="pdf_content" data="path/to/something.pdf?#zoom=75&amp;scrollbar=0&amp;toolbar=1&amp;navpanes=0" type="application/pdf" style="width: 818px; height: 997px"></object>
</div>

Comment: it's practically a div in which I add an object, first time when I added it it worked, but afterwards, when I wanted to edit again and save, it keept on showing "saving"